# php sends/echoes '?' for each require_once

Tags: php, json, iis, special-characters, require-once

My PHP file sends a JSON-Result to some GET-Request.
The problem is, that I keep getting parsing errors on the client side. Looking at the result string I found that each result starts with several question marks (?).

Cutting my scripts down bit by bit I found that the result contains one ? for each require, include, require_once or include_once.
Strangely the ? are invisible if I run the request in a browser. But copying the result into a text editor they become visible.

My server is an IIS with php 7.1.7

The (simplified) code looks something like this:

**lookup.php**

```
<?php
  include_once 'common/server.php';
  echo $srv->QueryTable(qry_ItemList);
```

**server.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'constants.php';
require_once 'sql/queryNAV.php';

class JSON_Server
{
    public function QueryTable($SQLTextName)
    {
        $qry_result = /*(do SQL-Query)*/;
        return json_encode($qry_result);
    }
}
$srv = new JSON_RESTServer;
```

The request looks something like this:

```
http://s-mde/itemLookup.php?number=305475
```

... and the result might be something like this:

```
?????[{"Typ":"I","No_":"408835","Description":"Ds Scene it? Twilight","debugCounter":96},{"Typ":"L","No_":"100773","Description":"Axe Deo Roll Diverse 50ml Ro","debugCounter":96},{"Typ":"L","No_":"410296","Description":"Axe Duschgel Africa 250ml Fl.","debugCounter":96},{"Typ":"L","No_":"102939","Description":"Axe Duschgel Alaska 250ml Fl.","debugCounter":96},{"Typ":"L","No_":"408835","Description":"Ds Scene it? Twilight","debugCounter":96},{"Typ":"L","No_":"100332","Description":"Rexona Roll On Men Sport 50ml","debugCounter":96}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your file encoding? I've had similar problems while creating JSON responses to Android app from PHP. Solved it by encoding both sides with UTF-8, request and response.

Comment: Currently I hadn't even thought about encoding. The request is sent either from a browser address field or from a Java String via Android/Volley. The Response is a simple "echo $ResultString". How can I take influence on the encoding? Do I have to add a header?

Comment: I don't know which IDE you are using. I personally use Notepad++ (oldtimer lerl) for PHP and I just open .php file, go to Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8 and save. Just remember, while changing your encoding in Notepad++ you might get some scrambled chars, so copy full code first, change encoding and then paste it again.

Comment: Solved: As Mario stated, it had something to do with the php source encoding, but in this case it was the other way:
All my files were encoded as UTF-8. I opened them (btw.: I use NPP too) and changed the encoding to ANSI. Now it works as expected.
Strange, though, since I use a pretty modern environment:
PHP 7.1.7 running on IIS on Windows Server 2016.
I would have thought, this combination should be able to handle UTF-8 correctly(?).
Nevertheless: problem solved - Thank You.

Comment: Unicode text files (such as PHP code) can start with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), while ANSI doesn't know that. So if there are characters in front of `<?php` in the file, they're sent through (and as per mixing multiple encodings then maybe rendered as `?`). Solution: save your files **without BOM** - Notepad++ also has a setting/option for this.